# How do you experimentally determine the value of the Compton edge from data?

Tags: experimental-physics, electrons, scattering, spectroscopy, gamma-rays

A NaI scintillation detector was used to acquire the following data. In order to calibrate the detector, I fitted a Gaussian function to the photopeak. I now want to check that my measured value for the Compton edge matches the theoretical value. I have plotted the theoretical value on the graph below:
[image]

I used to think that the Compton edge would occur where the arrow indicates but I now understand that this is not the case due to the resolution of the detector being Gaussian limited. What I don't understand is how to locate the value of the Compton edge with uncertainty. Would it involve fitting a Guassian function again? But in this case, the peak of the Gaussian would be where the arrow is pointing and not where the measured value of the Compton edge should be...

Answer (score 0):

To find the Compton edge from data, you need the help of a Monte Carlo (MC) simulation of your detector setup using GEANT4 or MCNPX. Your Monte Carlo will show the sharp falling Compton edge (Klein-Nishina Compton scattering endpoint). However, the detector's finite resolution will smear that sharp edge into a Compton maxima instead of a clear edge- you can emulate that by folding your MC truth energy deposition with a Gaussian function that has a width matching the detector resolution. Fit your simulated Compton maxima with a Gaussian or half-Gaussian function and find an empirical relation to relate its mean ($\mu$) and width ($\sigma$) to the true Compton edge, C as

$C = \mu + \epsilon \cdot \sigma$.

Now, you can use this $\epsilon$ parameter determined from simulation and the resulting Gaussian fit parameters obtained from data to locate the Compton edge.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).